# Android crash reporting using ACRA

Tags: android, acra

How can I set up my project for sending crash report using ACRA. I read some posts but am not able to do it.

I got some details in http://code.google.com/p/acra/wiki/ACRAHowTo#Setting-up_your_project but it would not work for me

```
12-15 14:06:06.221: WARN/System.err(2972): java.net.UnknownHostException: Host is unresolved: spreadsheets.google.com:80
12-15 14:08:11.111: WARN/System.err(3050): java.net.UnknownHostException: Host is unresolved: spreadsheets.google.com:80
12-15 14:08:11.111: WARN/System.err(3050):     at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:1037)
12-15 14:08:11.111: WARN/System.err(3050):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpConnection.<init>(HttpConnection.java:62)
12-15 14:08:11.121: WARN/System.err(3050):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpConnectionManager$ConnectionPool.getHttpConnection(HttpConnectionManager.java:145)
12-15 14:08:11.121: WARN/System.err(3050):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpConnectionManager.getConnection(HttpConnectionManager.java:67)
12-15 14:08:11.132: WARN/System.err(3050):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getHTTPConnection(HttpURLConnection.java:821)
12-15 14:08:11.151: WARN/System.err(3050):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(HttpURLConnection.java:807)
12-15 14:08:11.151: WARN/System.err(3050):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1150)
12-15 14:08:11.161: WARN/System.err(3050):     at org.acra.HttpUtils.doPost(HttpUtils.java:87)
12-15 14:08:11.172: WARN/System.err(3050):     at org.acra.ErrorReporter.sendCrashReport(ErrorReporter.java:537)
12-15 14:08:11.172: WARN/System.err(3050):     at org.acra.ErrorReporter.checkAndSendReports(ErrorReporter.java:632)
12-15 14:08:11.180: WARN/System.err(3050):     at org.acra.ErrorReporter.handleException(ErrorReporter.java:443)
12-15 14:08:11.191: WARN/System.err(3050):     at org.acra.ErrorReporter.handleException(ErrorReporter.java:459)
12-15 14:08:11.191: WARN/System.err(3050):     at org.acra.ErrorReporter.uncaughtException(ErrorReporter.java:335)
12-15 14:08:11.201: WARN/System.err(3050):     at java.lang.ThreadGroup.uncaughtException(ThreadGroup.java:887)
12-15 14:08:11.211: WARN/System.err(3050):     at java.lang.ThreadGroup.uncaughtException(ThreadGroup.java:884)
12-15 14:08:11.220: WARN/System.err(3050):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suspect no DNS on the device?  Can you browse to spreadsheets.google.com on the browser in the device?